# Project Euler 36 Double-base Palindrome Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I am trying to solve this problem and its not working (python 3)

**The decimal number, 585 = 10010010012 (binary), is palindromic in both bases.
Find the sum of all numbers, less than one million, which are palindromic in base 10 and base 2.
(Please note that the palindromic number, in either base, may not include leading zeros.)**

https://projecteuler.net/problem=36

```
def isPal(number):
##    if (len(number)<2):
##        return True
##    else:
##        return (number[0] == number[-1]) and isPal(number[1:-1])
    return(number == number[::-1])

total = 0
## generating palindromes, by increasing right side  y one and then mirroring to left
import math
digits = 2
number = [0]*digits
while(True):
    if (number == [9]*digits):
        digits+=1
        if (digits == 7):  # "under 1 million"
            break          # done with while(True) because else the digits +=1 would be at bottom
        number = [0]*digits
    number[-1] += 1
# number rolling over
    if (number[-1] == 10): 
        number[-2]+=1           
        number[-1]=1 
        for i in range(2,math.floor(digits/2)+1):         
            if (number[-i] == 10):          
                number[-(i+1)]+=1           
                number[-i]=0                
# mirroring image
    for j in range(1,math.floor(digits/2)+1):
        number[j-1] = number[-j]
    intNumber = 0
    for k in range(len(number)):
        intNumber += number[k]*(10**k)
    if isPal("{0:b}".format(intNumber)):
        total += intNumber
        print("      ",intNumber)
        print("{0:b}".format(intNumber))
print(total)
```

the answer given is 872162, which is wrong

Please help

Comment: The best advice I can give - follow the code and thing what your logic aims to achieve. Also, print the list of numbers your script produces. From quick skimming I can see that you don't count all number (for example - it seems that you don't count 1).

Comment: I would suggest you start by simplifying your code.  Instead of trying to create the strings yourself, you can use `for i in range(1,1000000): numbers=str(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... This is a very interesting approach. I like your idea! However your implementation is somewhat difficult to read through!

Anyway to address your question: The error is that you are not checking all of the palindromes in the range of 1 to 1000000! Namely you are missing the "special case" 1 digit palindromes (1 to 9)! So you are missing the numbers 1,3,5,7 and 9 (Corresponding to 1, 11, 101, 111, 1001).

Now for the friendly advice portion of my answer: don't reinvent the wheel! If you are implementing your own array representation of the integers you have probably over complicated things! Instead, for short math-y questions like this translate the English directly into code and *then* optimize:

```
total = 0
for i in range(1,1000000):
    if isDecPalindrome(i) and isBinPalindrome(i):
        total+=i
print(total)
```

This code is easy to read and organizes your thoughts! Now all you have to do is implement `isDecPalindrome` and `isBinPalindrome`!

Now you are probably saying, "But, Michael! In my code I only iterated through things I **knew** were palindromes!" True enough. But we can easily modify this code to incorporate that idea!

```
total = 0
for decPalindrome in decPalindromeGen(1,1000000):
    if isBinPalindrome(decPalindrome):
        total += decPalindrome 
print(total)
```

Now we again have a well organized "template" for our solution. For anyone reading this code for the first time it is very easy to understand what we are doing! For you the coder you have made your life easier by splitting your code into 1 function 1 generator and one main loop!

In case you are not familiar with generators, one possible defintion for `decPalindromeGen` is:

```
def decPalindromeGen(l,u):
    for i in range(l,u):
        if isDecPalindrome(i):
            yield i
```

Where `isDecPalindrome` is some function you define to detect if the input is a palindrome in Base 10.

Hope this was enlightening :)

EDIT: To clarify my supplied definition of `decPalindromeGen` is no better than what I was doing in the first example without the generator. It was merely to show how you should split up the code. For a more efficient algorithm adjust `decPalindromeGen` to generate palindromes more intelligently.

Comment: No worries! These are things that you start to learn the more you write code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

```
def isPal(number):
    number = str(number)
    return (number == number[::-1])
def isBinPal(number):
     number = bin(number)[2:] # bin() returns a string in binary starting with "0b", so we drop the first two characters
    return (number == number[::-1])
sum(x for x in range(1000000) if isPal(x) and isBinPal(x))
```

Looking up built in functions like `bin` to convert a number to binary will save you a lot of trouble.  Also knowing some of the language features like generators will come in handy:)

Comment: if this more efficient? I mean after making corrections to mine I skip all non base 10 palindromes.                                                                                                       Thanks for your help

Comment: Efficient how?  On my machine my code runs in 560 ms and yours runs in 13.9 ms according to `timeit`, so yours is much more efficient at run time.  However, I'm willing to bet that my solution took a lot less time to write, so unless this function is going to be run millions of times the speed up might not be worth the extra time it took you to write and debug.  You should always think about efficiency in terms of computer time and your time.  In most situations your time is worth more.

Comment: However, if you really want/need the function to run as fast as possible then your solution is a clever way to get the run time down:)